# Meteor Animation

Tags: javascript, css, exception, animation, meteor

I am trying to implement an animation where an item animates to the left after it gets selected.
The following code works. But only about 80% of the time.

JS

```
//myItem
Template.myItem.rendered = function(){
  if(Session.get("selected_item") === this.data._id){
    $(this.firstNode).addClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this.firstNode).removeClass("selected");
  }
};

Template.myItem.events({
  "click .myItem": function(evt, template){
    Session.set("selected_item", this._id);
  }
});


//myItemList
Template.myItemList.helpers({
  items: function(){
    return Items.find();
  }
});
```

Templates

```
<template name="myItem">
  <div class="myItem">{{name}}</div>
</template>

<template name="myItemList">
  {{#each items}}
    {{> myItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

CSS

```
.myItem { transition: all 200ms 0ms ease-in; }
.selected { left: -20px; }
```

I also tried to wrap the code into a `Meteor.defer()` to make sure that really everything is ready to do the animation.

```
Template.myItem.rendered = function(){
  Meteor.defer(function() {
    if(Session.get("selected_item") === this.data._id){
      $(this.firstNode).addClass("selected");
    } else {
      $(this.firstNode).removeClass("selected");
    }
  });
};
```

But that results in this kind of error:

```
Exception from defer callback: TypeError {}
```

It would be great to see any ideas how to make the animation work every time.

**UPDATE**

[Krab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1363007/krab) got the right answer. The exception was coming from the `this` reference. I want to add some details. So here are two working versions on how to do the animation:

with `Meteor.defer()`

```
Template.myItem.rendered = function(){
  var instance = this;
  if(Session.get("selected_item") === this.data._id){
    Meteor.defer(function() {  
      $(instance.firstNode).addClass("selected"); //use "instance" instead of "this"
    });
  }
};
```

(We don't actually need the else block here because meteor will remove the `selected` class if it redraws the item.)

or with `$().animate()`

```
Template.myItem.rendered = function(){
  if(Session.get("selected_item") === this.data._id){
    $(this.firstNode).animate({
      left: "-20px"
    }, 300);
  }
};
```

If you use the jQuery approach you need to remove the CSS code.

```
.myItem { transition: all 200ms 0ms ease-in; }
.selected { left: -20px; }
```

Comment: So rendered callback is called when something is rendered, so why it should be called when something is selected? We should get more code.

Comment: The rendered callback is called on every `Session.set("selected_item", id);` . I added some code to make the overall context more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, because `this` pointer in defer callback isn't the same as if the code is executed directly in rendered callback

```
Template.myItem.rendered = function(){
  var self = this;
  Meteor.defer(function() {
    if(Session.get("selected_item") === self.data._id){
      $(self.firstNode).addClass("selected");
    } else {
      $(self.firstNode).removeClass("selected");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally overlooked the `this`in the defer function. After replacing `this` everything works just fine.